# What is the difference between these two LINQ expressions?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

I was doing some messing around with dbcontext / EF and both produce the same thing for my needs. Are these actually equivalent? Any interesting points to consider on the difference?

```
//Something
var user = dbContext.Set<User>()
.Include(u => u.Preferences).FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == userID);


//Something else
var user = dbContext.Set<User>().Where(u => u.Id == userID)
.Include(u => u.Preferences).FirstOrDefault();
```

..Just curious.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're functionally equivalent, and should result in the same SQL query being executed against the database (depending on how the Linq provider is implemented, of course).

Answer (score 0):

Like in @ThomasLevesque answer they're functionally equivalent.

More, EF translate them in the same expression tree (a where expression and a Join/UnionAll - in this case only a Join - expression to solve the Include).
So, a single EF provider returns always the same query.